# Can I repair HDD with completed_read_failure reported?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, bad-sectors

I have a broken HDD here. There were some problems reading from it so I ran on it

```
smartctl -t short
smartctl -a
```

The result is:

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      9412         129798890

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Completed_read_failure [90% left] (0-65535)
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
```

Also I saw in the upper part:

```
ATA Error Count: 9 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
```

I  am wondering if the hard-disk can be somehow repaired in this condition or if it can be just scrapped.

Comment: This type of error cannot be solved by you.

Answer (score 4):

Get whatever important information off this disk ASAP.  It is definitely failing and playing around with a failed disk in any sort of application will be trouble.

Summary:  Replace the disk ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

#### Your hard drive has [bad sectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_sector) and should be replaced as soon as possible.

- A SMART test ending in a read failure is never a good sign as it indicates that parts of the media are damaged. Data stored in the affected area may already have been lost or corrupted. It is very likely your drive will accumulate more bad sectors, leading to further data loss, and there is a significant risk of total failure.
- This is not a condition that can be fixed by the user. You should back up any data on the drive and replace it as soon as possible.